# Wrap widgets to give a stacked effect commonly seen when selecting multiple users

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on a case where I'm selecting users and it creates a stacked coin effect. [image]

I'm doing this via a Wrap (in case the user selects way more users than those that fit on one row):

```
  return Wrap(
    spacing: -18,
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      EditAddSelectedPersons(
        iconData: state.selectedPersons.length > 0 ? Icons.edit : Icons.add,
        showLabel: state.selectedPersons.length > 0 ? false : true,
      ),
      ...state.selectedPersons.asMap().entries.map((MapEntry entry) => MultiSelectPersonAvatar(index: entry.key, person: entry.value,)),
    ]
  );
```

Some extra context:

> The MultiSelectPersonAvatar is just a wrapper around CircleAvatar.
>
> EditAddSelectedPersons is a FlatButton.

Is there a way to reverse the "Stacking" so that the first element is on top (right now its at the bottom) and the next is below it and so on? Right now the first one is at the bottom and it goes up on the z-index.

So essentially:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't change the layout order or z axis (z-index for css folks). Instead I created a custom clipper that provided the same effect:

```
      return Wrap(
        spacing: -8,
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          EditAddSelectedPersons(
            iconData: state.selectedPersons.length > 0 ? Icons.edit : Icons.add,
            showLabel: state.selectedPersons.length > 0 ? false : true,
          ),
          ...state.selectedPersons.asMap().entries.map((MapEntry entry) => MultiSelectPersonAvatar(index: entry.key, person: entry.value,)),
        ]
      );
```

And then on the MultiSelectPersonAvatar there is a custom clipper:

```
class MultiSelectPersonAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Person person;
  final int index;

  const MultiSelectPersonAvatar({
    Key key,
    @required this.person,
    @required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: index == 0 ? null : LeftThirdCircularNotchClipper(),
      child: FallBackAvatarB64( //This is a circle avatar really
        imageB64: person.personImageB64, 
        initials: Utils.getInitials(person.name), 
        circleBackground: Consts.coPersonListAvatarMain, 
        textStyle: Consts.tsCardInput, 
        radius: 18, 
        personId: person.id
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then the custom clipper:

```
class LeftThirdCircularNotchClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0); //x, y
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(4, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 18, size.height/2, 4, 0); //x1, y1, x2, y2
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

This gives the final effect that looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless i understood your question incorrectly, I believe you can accomplish that by setting:

```
verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was as clear as it should have been. I've added a picture to further illustrate my questions.